# setTimeout stop scrolling function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, settimeout

I have this scroll function that checks for when the end of a div id reached:

```
function loadOldPosts() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://www.example.com/go.php",
            method: "post",
            data:{
                postID: postID
            },
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data)
            {
                if (data) {

                    setTimeout(loadOldPosts, 5000);

                }
            }

        });

    }

$(window).scroll(function() {

    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.scrollTop() + $this.height() >= $('#wall_posts').offset().top + $('#wall_posts').height() ) { 
        loadOldPosts();
    } 

});
```

I'm trying to make it so that once loadOldPosts runs, it must wait 5 seconds before being able to run again. I though I could accomplish this with setTimeout function but it does not seem to work.

How can I make it to that the function can only run once every 5 seconds at most?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with wait for next calling until ajax success/error using following example:

```
var loading  = true;
function loadOldPosts(){
   if(loading){
     loading  = false;
     $.ajax({
      ...,
      success:function(data){
         loading  = true;
      },
      error:function(data){
         loading  = true;
      }
     })     
   }
}
```